# How to improve dull images

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, emgucv

I have a C# winform app.
I am utilising Emgu framework to help me to detect motion between frames.

I have 1 issue.  At night time or when it is a dull image due to a dull day and the object I want to detect has low value colours (like black and brown and dark green) it is sometimes difficult to detect this motion.

I had hit upon the idea of enhancing the image when it is a dull image frame.

I would 1st have to work out the 'average' contrast of an image to determine whether I need to increase the contrast of that image.

What would be the best way to do this?

I have converted the RGB image to an HSV image. But I am unsure which values/channels to use to perceive whether the overall image is low in contrast.

I have looked around for a formula that would measure this based on Hue, Saturation and Luminance/brightness,

So far I have this:

C = ((100.0 + T) / 100.0)2 taken from this site: [enter link description here](http://softwarebydefault.com/2013/04/20/image-contrast/)

'T' is defined as the variable Threshold.  Now this is where I come unstuck. 
What is this variable threshold? 
What should I base it on?

Should I look elsewhere for an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look to [Histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) ? I use it to enhance automatically image contrast (but I used it only on grayscale images).

Comment: Hi, 1st thanks so much for your suggestion. So sorry it took so long to reply but I had to pop out and have only just seen this.  I have used Histogram Equalization before but then every frame seemed to show motion even when there was not.  Thanks for your offering though :)

Comment: If I can somehow measure the contrast levels in an image I could then lower the threshold on how I detect motion whee comparing the pixels.  Or/and I could enhance the saturation channels.  But I only want to do this for dull images

Comment: Then convert your images to HSL and set a treshhold for the Lighness.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts. This is lightness/brightness though and not contrast - but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ok I wasn't exactly sure how you defined dullness of the image. If you need to measure contracst you'll need to do a DCT on the image and put a treshhold on the frequencies

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in my response.  You were quite correct I should have been more specific. I shall look into DCT now.  Do you know if emgu/opencv/aforge has an inbuilt function for this?  Thanks

Comment: @MrPaulch HI, I not sure how I understand how to do this :).  Would you have any code I could look at?

Comment: Have a look at this code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43782/DCT-Implementation-in-C-DCT-of-Image

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I just need to work out what it all means now! :)